# How do I use nanohttpd websockets from a client app?

Tags: java, websocket, nanohttpd

I have implemented a websocket server using nanohttpd in java. I can access the websocket server from js in a web page. It works great.

However, now I'd like to create a java based client that will connect to the same server.

Does nanohttpd have a set of java classes to connect to the websocket server? In other words, the server is running in java but now I want a separate java client program to connect to it.

If so, what is the minimum java code to connect to the server?

If not, how would you suggest I connect to the websocket server in java?

Comment: Mark M, any chance that you could share your code?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of third party Java Web Socket client implementations you can use. [This](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) is one of them.